# NHibernate - define fetching strategy dynamically

Tags: nhibernate, select, nhibernate-mapping, eager-loading

Let me explain the problem - hopefully I have defined it well in the title but I want to be sure.

I have a linq query that pulls back a bunch of objects (say Foos). Each Foo holds a reference to a User. Each User holds a reference to a Person:

```
public class Foo
{
  //properties omitted...
  public User CreatedBy {get;}
}
public class User
{
  //properties omitted...
  public Person Person {get;set;}
}
```

As the object structure would suggest, in the database, Foo relates many-to-one to User, and User relates many-to-one to Person.

When I run the query, I get a single SELECT for the Foos, then a SELECT each for all the Users and People. Clearly I would much prefer a single SELECT with a couple of joins.

I don't necessarily want to specify in my mapping config that Foos ALWAYS eager fetch the User, or that Users ALWAYS eager fetch the Person, but I would like to be able to specify that in this instance.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

David

Comment: What means: "specify that in this instance"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the NHibernate query methods have ways of specifying eager fetching.

For **Criteria**, you have `SetFetchMode`.

For **HQL**, you have `[inner|left] join fetch`.

For **Linq** yo have `Expand` (2.x contrib) / `Fetch` (3.x).

For **SQL** you have `AddJoin`.

Comment: Thanks. It's Linq I want. Is this new version of Linq to NHibernate available now? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/3.0.0Alpha1/NHibernate-3.0.0.Alpha1-bin.zip/download

Comment: Alpha is just a name. Microsoft would call a product in the same state "Beta2" or "RC". NHibernate uses continuous integration, so this Alpha actually has *less* bugs than the stable 2.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/2007/09/16/fetching-strategy-nhibernate-implementation-available/) and [Ritesh Rao](http://www.codeinsanity.com/2009/02/fetching-strategy-and-adaptive-domain.html) offer example implementations of dynamic fetching strategies for NHibernate, this should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Diegos nice answer: You can also use batching. This reduces the N+1 problem without much pain:

use batch-size on class level:

```
<class name="Person" batch-size="20">
...
</class>
```

use batch-size on collection level:

```
<map
    name="SomeCollection"
    batch-size="20">
  ...
</map>
```

When ever one of these references is loaded, NHibernate loads 20 at once using a query like this:

```
select ... from Person where user_fk in (23, 34, 6, 667, 6745, 234 ....)
```

So it turns `N+1` to `N / 20 + 1`, which is pretty good.